# How $block->getChildHtml(); data passes in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2

Magento default customer.phtml file in the directory of magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account has the following code in line 42 which shows a dropdown list when logged in.

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
```

Where the functionalities declared for this file?

Answer (score 1):

the **getChildHtml()** declared at \Magento\Core\Block\AbstrackBlock, Object **$block** is class extended **AbstrackBlock**, 
the function will call all child block of **current** block and call **toHtml()** function, suggest use **get_class($block)** to get class name of **$block**. or find in template xml file where defined customer.phtml and find block class name..

**read more:**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html